# "Bisognare" versus "essere necessario" o "doversi"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, verbs, difference

Mi piacerebbe avere dei chiarimenti sull'uso del verbo impersonale "bisognare". Ho l'impressione (ma non ne sono sicura) che si usi soltanto in un registro formale e che "essere necessario" o "doversi" (con un uso impersonale) siano molto più frequenti nel linguaggio comune. È così? Ad esempio, parlando con qualcuno della febbre commerciale di questi giorni, potrei dire

> - La pubblicità ci fa credere che *bisogni* spendere molti soldi per dimostrare amore a una persona

ma non so se sarebbe meglio dire

> - La pubblicità ci fa credere che *sia necessario* spendere molti soldi per dimostrare amore a una persona

oppure

> - La pubblicità ci fa credere che *si debbano* spendere molti soldi per dimostrare amore a una persona.

Comment: "dimostrare amore" (senza articolo) è la forma comunemente usata. Con l'articolo si potrebbe dire "dimostrare il proprio amore".

Comment: Grazie! Adesso faccio la correzione.

Comment: In realtà 'febbre commerciale' in Italia in questi giorni se ne vede poca. Studi mostrano che solo il 25% delle famiglie non userà la tredicesima per pagare tasse e debiti.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

La risposta pragmatica è che ormai si usa solo come verbo modale e solo nella terza persona singolare: "bisogna", "bisognerebbe", "bisognerà", etc. e anche così, certi tempi/modi verbali, pur corretti, suonano strani (ad es. il congiuntivo "bisogni"). In quei casi si usano perifrasi come "si deve", "è necessario", "c'è bisogno" etc.

Nel tuo caso, la prima frase non si userebbe comunemente (per quanto ne so io), mentre la seconda e la terza sì.

Answer (score 3):

Non ho ancora abbastanza "reputation" per un commento.

No, @Charo, non corrisponde al caso 1 perché stai usando, giustamente, il congiuntivo. Come ha detto @Karoshi, "bisognare" si usa ancora ma limitato alla terza persona dell'indicativo. Quindi se tu dicessi: "bisogna spendere molti soldi..." suonerebbe bene, ma visto che la tua frase richiede il congiuntivo io sceglierei "che sia necessario" o "che si debbano".

Comment: Capisco: grazie mille!

Answer (score -2):

Siccome il congiuntivo presente è usato per indicare eventi visti come non reali o non obiettivi o non rilevanti, non puoi usarlo con 'bisognare' perché in italiano se una cosa bisogna bisogna e basta, senza se e senza ma.

Inoltre 'bisogna' non è un vocabolo che si usa in contesti formali perché, contrariamente alla sua natura apodittica, lì è necessario argomentare ed essere interlocutòri.