# Difference between "impiegare", "necessitare", and "aver bisogno di"

Tags: word-usage, meaning, difference

What is the real difference between ***impiegare***, ***necessitare (di qualcuno/qualcosa)*** and ***aver bisogno di***?

I know *necesitar* from Spanish, and *avoir besoin de...* from French, but Italian having both and  *impiegare* is new to me.

Can please someone enlighten me about which one to use, and when? Are they interchangeable?

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Comment: The meaning of *impiegare* has no relation with the other two verbs'. What makes you think it has?

Comment: because of this translator http://deit.dict.cc/?s=brauchen ("brauchen" is 'to need' in German) So the translation might simply be wrong?

Comment: Quite wrong, yes. *Impiegare* means essentialy “to use [something to do something]”, and is almost a synonym of *usare*. See [here](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/impiegare/) for more.

Comment: This is [a related question](http://italian.stackexchange.com/q/3724/707), but you need to understand Italian.

Comment: "Necessitare di" and "avere bisogno di" are in principle synonymous (they mean "to need" something), but the meanings of "impiegare" are completely different: it can mean "to use" something or "to hire" someone for a job.

Comment: Actually there are some circumstances where "impiegare" can be used as synonym of "necessitare di" and "avere bisogno di". This happens when you enumerate the resources that you normally employ to do something, for instance, you can say "impiego due ore per fare questo lavoro" instead of "ho bisogno di due ore per fare questo lavoro".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Impiegare** is often used with time notions.

For exemple: To take me 1 hour to go to school.
             *Impiegare 1 ora per andare a scuola.*

**Necessitare** is mostly written. By oral, you'll nearby never heard it. The only way you can use it is in manuals, in recipes, lists of material you need... It's not very often used.

For exemple: To cook this cake, you need 3 eggs.
             *Per cucinare questa torta, necessitano 3 uova.*

**Aver bisogno** is often used with objects or people. It means more or less "to need" in English. Aver bisogno is very often used by oral.

For exemple: I need your help.
             *Ho bisogno del tuo aiuto.*

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE, @VinzSfr! A me piacerebbe sapere qualcosa di più sull'uso di "necessitare". Soltanto adesso ho scoperto che si tratta di un "falso amico" del "necessitar" catalano e del "necesitar" spagnolo nel senso che l'uso transitivo di "necessitare" è diventato obsoleto (beh, perlomeno questo è ciò che ho trovato nei dizionari), mentre i verbi simili in catalano e spagnolo li usiamo sempre in modo transitivo.

Comment: Nell'esempio che hai messo nella tua risposta si fa un uso impersonale di "necessitare" simile a quello dei verbi, che penso si usino di più, "occorrere", "servire" o "volerci", no? Cioè, potrei parafrasare il tuo esempio così?: "Per cucinare questa torta, occorrono 3 uova", "Per cucinare questa torta, servono 3 uova", "Per cucinare questa torta, ci vogliono 3 uova".

Comment: Ma poi, se ho capito bene quello che ho letto nei dizionari, si fa anche uso di "necessitare di", che non è impersonale e che è più o meno sinonimo di "avere bisogno di" (ma forse è più formale e meno usato). Per esempio, "Maria necessita di una macchina per andare al lavoro". È così?

Comment: Ciao. Sì, devo admettere che ho avuto un pò di difficoltà per trovare l'esempio con le uova ^.^ . Ma in certe regioni del sud come la Sicilia (regione delle mie origini)  ho a volte sentito questo verbo (che suonava  un pò strano). Dunque non direi che non sia più utilisato ma in teoria (dizionari) è possibile che sia disperso. Grazie per la tua riflessione.

Comment: Sì, esatto. "Maria necessita di una macchina per andare al lavoro" può essere interpretato come giusto.

Comment: Che cosa intendi per «This verb is theoretically not used (it doesn't appear in dictionaries)»? Hai visto [qui](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/necessitare/), [qui](http://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/necessitare) e in qualsiasi altro dizionario? Anzi, mi dici un dizionario in cui non appare?

Comment: Scusa DaG ho fatto una ricerca ma ero distratto. In effetti c'era. Grazie per il commento.

Comment: Ma il costrutto impersonale appare nei vocabolari! Esempio tratto dallo Zingarelli (dodicesima edizione): "Necessita la vostra sincerità". Se ho capito bene quello che ho letto nei dizionari, questa forma impersonale si trova spesso seguita da "che + congiuntivo": "Necessita che il lavoro sia terminato al più presto" (lo Zingarelli).

Comment: Quello che stavo cercando di dire è che i dizionari sembrano indicare due usi diversi di "necessitare": uno che è impersonale e un altro che non lo è. Per esempio: "L'edificio necessita di manutenzione" (lo Zingarelli).

Comment: @DaG: Do you think that this answer is incomplete in the sense of what I'm trying to say in my comments? I would like to know your opinion because, even if I can read dictionaries, I'm not Italian and actually I do not know nothing about the real use of the verb "necessitare".

Answer (score 1):

The most general Italian verbs/phrases to convey the sense of “to need” are **avere bisogno (di)** and **occorrere**. For instance, “I need help” is *Ho bisogno di aiuto* or *Mi occorre aiuto*. The latter is less colloquial, more literary than the former.

Another way to say this is with the impersonal use of the verb **servire**; so, the above example could also be translated as *Mi serve aiuto*. In a sense, *avere bisogno* emphasises the actual need, while *servire* borders on “I could use [whatever]”.

Some uses of “to need” are better conveyed by a colloquial construction with the verb **volere**. To say that to make some cake one needs two eggs, you might say *Per quel dolce ci vogliono* [but also *servono*] *tre uova*. Or *ci vuole un bel fegato* for “it takes a lot of guts [to do something]”.

**Necessitare** is more along the lines of “to be in need of”, but it sounds presently quite affected. Note that in modern Italian (and in this meaning) it is usually constructed with *di*: so, for the previous example, *Necessito di aiuto*. **Essere necessario** is somewhat more usual, especially in regulations and the like: *È necessario inserire la password* (“You have to insert your password”).

Finally, the main meanings of **impiegare** are parallel to those of “to employ”, both in the “give work” and in the “make use of” senses. It may be used in a vaguely similar sense to the “need” meaning, in sentences like *Il treno impiega tre ore per arrivare a Firenze*, that is, “It takes three hours for the train to reach Florence” (but most people, in ordinary speech, would probably say *Il treno ci mette tre ore*).

For further nuances about some of these terms, the *Dizionario dei sinonimi* by Niccolò Tommaseo is as always enlightening, even if it is about 150 years old. For the present topic, who desires to strike out into 19th-century Italian will be rewarded by reading [here](https://archive.org/stream/dizionariodeisi00tomm#page/684/mode/2up).

Comment: Grazie di questa risposta così completa, @DaG! È davvero utile! Soltanto una domanda: la forma impersonale di "necessitare" (ho riportato un paio di esempi dallo Zingarelli nei miei commenti) non è molto usata attualmente?

Comment: Confermo, @Charo, mi suona come qualcosa che potrei trovare in un testo di vari decenni fa.

Answer (score 0):

**Impiegare** means that you use something for a purpose. For instance,  you can use *impiegare* to say that you use your bike in order to go to school.

**Necessitare** means that you really need something or someone, which is extremely important for your purpose.

**Aver bisogno di** means that you need something or someone, but it's not really necessary, you simply would like to have it.

Sorry I can't explain better than this ;)

Comment: I don't understand why "aver bisogno di" implies that something is not really necessary. If I say, for instance, "Le piante hanno bisogno di ossigeno per vivere", that means that oxygen is not really necessary for plants?

Comment: That is the flexibility of Italian language,
you could say "Maria ha bisogno di una macchina per andare a lavoro" which means that Maria needs a car but it's not really necessary, she could also use public transport.
But "Maria necessita una macchina per andare a lavoro" means that the only way to get to work is a car, otherwise Maria cannot reach her job location.
Does it make more sense?

Comment: Ma veramente è così? Non ho trovato questa sfumatura in nessun dizionario. E non sarebbe più comune scrivere "Maria necessita di una macchina per andare al lavoro"? Secondo il [dizionario De Mauro](http://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/necessitare) l'uso transitivo di "necessitare" è obsoleto.

Comment: I see where Marcello is coming from, but maybe change it to 'but it can also be used to mean something that is asked for, but not the only option'?